# Github outdated diff functionality

Tags: github

Did the "outdated diff functionality" get removed or are we just using comments wrong now?

Whenever a updated a review comment I no longer get the "outdated diff functionality". This makes it extremely hard to keep track of what was updated when working with a team.

Cheers.

**Edit**

Received an e-mail from github that explained the functionality is no longer active and that they are working on bringing it back again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Received an e-mail from github that explained the functionality is no longer active and that they are working on bringing it back again.

**It has been restored.**

Comment: Did they remove it from the new PR system introduced the past couple weeks? I seem to have lost the outdated diff functionality..

Comment: @KevinGrant it has been restored a while ago so it is working again(just checked a couple minutes ago and still does). Something else might be going on with your pull request.